# Geometry nodes: Alter the radius of a curve to make it look like a worm (by repeating a pattern)

Tags: geometry-nodes

I made a basic "tube" from a curve, using Geometry Nodes.

[image]

and I would like to alter the curve radius to make it look like a worm that has segments:

[image]

I guess I should draw a "pattern" that should be repeated along the curve, eg. with a Float Curve Node.

[image]

How could I achieve that ?  Here's my [actual blend](https://filedn.eu/lDv4C27hDkbRzM3b8NHRBTz/GN-tube.blend).

Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 4):

use this node setup:

[image]

to get this:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An adjustment to your method might be as follows:

[image]

.. mapping the (0-1) Spline Parameter range to  N (0-1) segments, to make them suitable for the *Float Curve* node, and further adjusting its output to give a base radius, and scale the *Float Curve*'s contribution, on top of that.

[image]